# Lego on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, minor-katan-child, games-toys

Is Lego Muktzeh? and can Adults use it too?

Comment: Why would you think it's muktzeh?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

http://www.hakhel.info/archivesCABs/HAKHELCOMMUNITYAWARENESSBULLETINSummerPart25764.pdf

"Any toy that needs to be screwed together is prohibited because of the issur of Boneh.
Therefore, one may not play with a construction set on Shabbos. On the other hand,
because one merely sticks together the pieces, one is permitted to play with Legos,
Tinkertoys and the like on Shabbos."

Teshuvos written by HaRav Yisroel Belsky, Shlita

Comment: Thanx alot  Curiouser

Comment: There is definitely a machloket on this - I have seen some hilchot shabbat books forbid it, some permit it, and some permit it only if it is intended to be taken apart relatively quickly. See your LOR.

Answer (score 12):

You seem to be asking two questions here:

- Is Lego© Mutar for an adult to use? How about a child?
- If it's only Mutar for a child, does that render it muktze for an adult?

(Perhaps I'm reading into your question because of the availability of my answer, but either way it will address your question.)

Hacham Ovadia Yosef, in Yechave Da'at (2:55), Addresses Lego©. (He starts off by saying that if something is Assur for adults, then its Assur for children too, yet) he seems to conclude that *it's fine for children to play with Lego© on shabbat, but adults should stay away*. He argues mostly that there's no *melacha* according to the Shulchan Aruch, but seems to be machmir for adults anyway (possibly because he is *choshesh* for the opinions that are *machmir*.) He restates this conclusion in Yabia Omer (O"C 7:39), where he says, "העלתי שמותר לתת ***לקטן*** 'אבני פלא' וכיו"ב לשחק בהם להרכיבם ולפרקם"

Regarding muktze, Hacham Ovadia in Yabia Omer (ibid.) says that Lego© is not *muktze* for an adult:

> וגם נראה שמותר לגדול לתת לקטן לשחק בצעצועים המיוחדים לקטנים, ואין בהם
>   משום מוקצה

Harav E. Y. Waldenberg, in Tzitz Eliezer (13:30), (also quoted in Yabia Omer, among other modern *poskim* that Hacham Ovadia quotes,) rules that Lego© is completely mutar, even for an adult:

> (From 13:30.6)
>
> בהא נחיתנא ובהא סליקנא דאין כל איסור בונה או סותר בבנית או סתירת אבני
>   - פלא שהילדים שוחקים בהם.   וגם לרבות לא משום תיקון מנא.   ומותר לשחק בהם בשבת.   בכבוד רב וביקר אליעזר יהודה וולדינברג.‏

He backs up this *pesaq din* in 13:31, the following *siman*.

Answer (score 7):

If the blocks are easily removed - even adults can play it.

But if you need to apply some force in order to connect/remove the blocks it more miskaem, so there 
are different opinions on that case. When I asked about it my Rav he told that even in latter case there is no problem for adults to play it. However I've heard others that forbid playing hard-stucking lego to adults.

In any case, even if just children are allowed to play it - it is not a muktze.

Comment: I need sources or even who you asked that told you this

Comment: in view of a number of similar active questions, it may be worth reminding everyone of the message in red print at the top of this page. For questions like this, one should always consult their own Rav.

Comment: Fair enough Jeremy; but I think it's a good question, everyone has "heard" the Lego is a problem for grownups, but it would be nice to know which poskim actually said it.

Comment: I have heard jutky's answer, but hard for whom to remove?  The user?

Comment: anyone find anything to agree with Jutky claim that some say it is OK

Comment: I've asked my Rav, he lives in Bnei-Brak and his name is Refael Antin (there is no chance you can know him).
Source to the opposite opinion: שמירת שבת כהלכתה  פרק ט"ז , הלכה י"ח
He says that it is allowed to plays blocks that are easily removed, but it they are not easily removed it is forbidden, and in any case He says in halakha aleph that all toys are allowed just for children and not for adults. But there is a slight discussion in heara נ"ג, so the conclusion is a bit dimmed.

Comment: See my answer for sources of heter and the sources quoted therein (is that a word?) for sources of those who argue.

Comment: @jutky Maybe put that source (שמירת שבת כהלכתה) in the body of the answer itself? ....I know it's a little late, but I just got here....

Answer (score 3):

Great answer by Baal Shemot Tovot
though extra sources brought [here](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/lego-on-shabbos.html):

> R' Pesach Eliyahu Falk (Machazeh Eliyahu 69) writes that while joining two pieces together is permissible, one shouldn't even allow one’s children to play with Lego on Shabbos because building models could come under the prohibition of kesiva, and building a house with a roof could be creating an ohel.
>
> Yet, many poskim including the Tzitz Eliezer (13:30-31) permit it. Seemingly, other poskim are primarily concerned for the prohibition of boneh. Both the Shemiras Shabbos Kehilchasa (16:18) and R' Belsky write that while construction sets that need screwing together are included in the prohibition of boneh, one is allowed to play with lego on Shabbos.
>
> While R' Ovadia Yosef allows it (Yechave Daas 2:55 and Yabia Omer OC 7:39), he suggests that because of the above concerns, adults should ideally refrain from Lego building, though children may do so.
>
> In conclusion, it is best not to build complete models or buildings on Shabbos, though it is okay to assist children with their Lego building

Comment: Classic Rabbi Falk

Answer (score 0):

Dinonline [writes](http://dinonline.org/2013/01/27/lego-on-shabbos/),

> It is permitted to play with lego on Shabbos, in particular where the
>   purpose is not to leave the construction for a long time. For lego
>   that will be left for a long time (sometimes true for small lego), one
>   should be stringent.
>
> Sources:
>
> Where pieces are not fixed in place strongly, and it is normal to put
>   them together and take them apart, it is permitted to play with lego
>   (Minchas Shlomo 1:11).
>
> See also Rabbi Pesach Eliyahu Falk (Shut Machazeh Eliyahu), who is
>   likewise lenient for matters of boneh, but is stringent with regard to
>   small lego because of the issue of “writing” (sculpting).

Answer (score -2):

I have heard an opinion that it is permitted even for adults simply because the intended purpose of the Lego product is to put together and then take apart. Therefore, it's status would not change based on personal intentions or whether they are easy or hard for the user to take apart.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It's most likely because you bring no source for your claims. You simply said "I heard." Heard from who? Your rabbi? Your neighbor?