# Is playing with Legos© permissible on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, shabbat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lego on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4920/lego-on-shabbos)

I have wondered this for a while. It would seem that it would be forbidden under creative building. Is there a difference regarding whether one tears apart whatever he creates before the end of Shabbat? I would also assume that the ruling would extend to Yom Tov as well, since there isn't much of a difference when it comes to building on Yom Tov. Is playing with Legos© or Duplos© or Lincoln Logs© (etc.) forbidden under building on Shabbat and Chag?

Comment: FYI, its officially "Lego©", not "Legos" ;)